# Codeigniter query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My Query :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('pos_item_sales', 'pos_item_sales.item_id = pos_item_infos.item_id');
$this->db->join('pos_batch_infos', 'pos_batch_infos.item_id = pos_item_infos.item_id');
$this->db->where("`pos_item_sales`.`transaction_id` =  '$transaction_id' AND (`pos_item_sales`.`item_barcode` =  '$term' OR `pos_batch_infos`.`item_mbarcode` =  '$term' OR `pos_item_infos`.`item_id` =  '$term')");
$query = $this->db->get('pos_item_infos');
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

its solve my prob but i need like this query :

```
$term = $this->input->get('term',TRUE);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('pos_item_sales', 'pos_item_sales.item_id = pos_item_infos.item_id');
$this->db->join('pos_batch_infos', 'pos_batch_infos.item_id = pos_item_infos.item_id');
$this->db->where('pos_item_sales.transaction_id',$transaction_id);
$this->db->where('pos_item_sales.item_barcode',$term);
$this->db->or_where('pos_batch_infos.item_mbarcode',$term);
$this->db->or_where('pos_item_infos.item_id',$term);
$query = $this->db->get('pos_item_infos');
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

But I need a Query like :

```
SELECT *
FROM (`pos_item_infos`)
JOIN `pos_item_sales` ON `pos_item_sales`.`item_id` = `pos_item_infos`.`item_id`
JOIN `pos_batch_infos` ON `pos_batch_infos`.`item_id` = `pos_item_infos`.`item_id`
WHERE `pos_item_sales`.`transaction_id` =  '11355822927'
AND (`pos_item_sales`.`item_barcode` =  '8801962686156'
OR `pos_batch_infos`.`item_mbarcode` =  '8801962686156'
OR `pos_item_infos`.`item_id` =  '8801962686156')
```

how i solve this prob pls help because its not include ( ) in my or condition.

Comment: so what is wrong with your first code??? that should work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you go through the [codeigniter userguide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).. you can see that there are 4 ways to call `where` clause...

All of these does the same things... and your first code is **codeigniter style** (if incase you are worried that is not) that is the 4th method by codeigniter userguide **where you can write your own clauses manually**... there is no difference in calling the where function in anyways...

so i would go with your first query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('pos_item_sales', 'pos_item_sales.item_id = pos_item_infos.item_id');
$this->db->join('pos_batch_infos', 'pos_batch_infos.item_id = pos_item_infos.item_id');
$this->db->where("`pos_item_sales`.`transaction_id` =  '$transaction_id' AND (`pos_item_sales`.`item_barcode` =  '$term' OR `pos_batch_infos`.`item_mbarcode` =  '$term' OR `pos_item_infos`.`item_id` =  '$term')");
$query = $this->db->get('pos_item_infos');
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

which is perfectly fine...

Answer (score 1):

In cases of complex queries i find it easier to just send raw query like this :

`$query = "your query";`

`$result = $this->db->query($query);`

Don't forget to escape variables before inserting them to the query like this :

`$var = $this->db->escape($var);`

Comment: my first query works fine but its a manual query . i need codeigniter style .

Comment: `$query="SELECT *
FROM (`pos_item_infos`)
JOIN `pos_item_sales` ON `pos_item_sales`.`item_id` = `pos_item_infos`.`item_id`
JOIN `pos_batch_infos` ON `pos_batch_infos`.`item_id` = `pos_item_infos`.`item_id`
WHERE `pos_item_sales`.`transaction_id` =  '11355822927'
AND (`pos_item_sales`.`item_barcode` =  '8801962686156'
OR `pos_batch_infos`.`item_mbarcode` =  '8801962686156'
OR `pos_item_infos`.`item_id` =  '8801962686156')"`

this is codeigniter style.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT *
FROM pos_item_infos
JOIN pos_item_sales ON pos_item_sales.item_id = pos_item_infos.item_id
JOIN pos_batch_infos ON pos_batch_infos.item_id = pos_item_infos.item_id
WHERE pos_item_sales.transaction_id =  ?
AND (pos_item_sales.item_barcode =  ?
OR pos_batch_infos.item_mbarcode =  ?
OR pos_item_infos.item_id =  ?)";
$params=array();
$params[]='11355822927';
$params[]='8801962686156';
$params[]='8801962686156';
$params[]='8801962686156';


$result=$this->db->query($query,$params);
$result=$result->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

Also, simplify your syntax with `USING`.

```
SELECT *
FROM pos_item_infos
JOIN pos_item_sales USING (item_id)
JOIN pos_batch_infos USING (item_id)
WHERE pos_item_sales.transaction_id =  ?
AND (pos_item_sales.item_barcode =  ?
OR pos_batch_infos.item_mbarcode =  ?
OR pos_item_infos.item_id =  ?)
```